# Can't click on this button selenium webdriver python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to click on this button from hours, no way to do it.
I tried to find it in all ways XPATH exc..
The button is inside an iframe "iframeGioco" i also switched to it, but still nothing.

Please help me out.

This is the html source:

[image]

I need to click on the highlighted div that is a button or in the next div contains "OK".

I did a lot of scripts with selenium but this button is really hard to click.
I would link the page but i can't, because you should have an eurobet account to see this page.

Thank you.

example of my tries:

```
browser.switch_to_frame(browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//iframe[@id="iframeGioco"]'))

browser.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='rounded-corners no-highlight ftl-error-buttonise absolute-horz-center']").click()
```

NB: THE STRANGE THING IS THAT I DON'T GET AN ERROR LIKE "NOSUCHELEMENT" I DON'T GET NOTHING, SO I THINK THE ELEMENT IS FOUND BUT THE CLICK DOESN'T WORK FOR SOME REASON.

[image: NEED TO CLICK "OK" BUTTON]

THE BUTTON TO CLICK IS THE "OK" BUTTON IN THE IMG.

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: The strange thing is that i don't get any error, but the click doesn't work. so i think the element is found

Comment: Please try click with JS —->. driver.execute_script(“arguments[0].click();”, webElement).   This will clear that element is receiving click or not. Try it without wait. Else it can fail on wait

Comment: Thank you i try it right now and let you know, your help is apprecciated

Comment: Guys i don't know how to regreet you, it worked with javascript.execute_script(), i need 2 more rep to upvote your answers :(, what can i do for you?

Comment: I can post it as answer if you say then you can accept it as answer

Comment: Yes sure, post.

Comment: I have added it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To click on `OK` div element which is inside an `iframe`

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it`()

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and `element_to_be_clickable`() and following `Xpath`

```
WebDriverWait(browser,20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"iframeGioco")))
WebDriverWait(browser,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[text()='OK']"))).click()
```

OR

```
WebDriverWait(browser,20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"iframeGioco")))
WebDriverWait(browser,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[contains(.,'OK')]"))).click()
```

You need to add following libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

---

UPDATE

Induce Javascript executor to click.

```
WebDriverWait(browser,20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"iframeGioco")))
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", WebDriverWait(browser,20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[contains(.,'OK')]"))))
```

Comment: I get "TimeoutException"

Comment: @alessiaresto : Have you tried the second one as well?Under OR

Comment: If both samples are throwing the `TimeoutException`, you could also try invoking `WebDriverWait` on `presence_of_element_located` instead of `element_to_be_clickable` -- that may make a difference.

Comment: It works without errors,also EC.tobeclickable, but the element is not effectively clicked.

Comment: @alessiaresto : can you try the update one and let me know the status

Comment: @KunduK If your intention is to `click()` why `presence_of_element_located()`?

Comment: @DebanjanB : When I posted the answer `element_to_be_clickable()` the OP said he is getting time out exception don't know why??and then someone suggest use `presence_of_element_located()` then we come to know it is the problem of normal webdriver clicking.Then suggest javascript executor option.

Comment: @KunduK _...When you are answering a question, you are not talking directly to OP. You are talking over your shoulder to a much larger audience...._

Comment: No I was talking directly to OP only if you see OP comment with my conversation.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to click with JS as it work differently.

Webdriver work as we/user do manually. If element is not enabled even user can see it on page it will not click while JS is client side script and it talk to directly browser (with help of built in interpreter)

Please try with below code.

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", webElement)
```

Comment: Do you understood why with JS worked and with standard "click" not?

Comment: @Nuclearz  reason is webdriver work as we/user do manually. If element is not enabled even user can see it on page it will not click while JS is client side script and it talk to directly browser (with help of built in interpreter)

Comment: @Muzzamil The comment on _webdriver work_ vs JSclick, if appended to the answer will make it a great answer and will be helpful to the community.

Comment: @DebanjanB  Thanks for the suggestion. I have added it to my answer.